# How to configure npm proxy for the companies Zscaler settings?

Tags: npm

0

In my company I can't download the node modules via npm, because the connection is being refused. We use a Zscaler with a .pac config file. I tried to configure the proxy via various tutorials

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy

https://www.jhipster.tech/configuring-a-corporate-proxy/

but I don't get it to work. When I type

```
npm --proxy http://username:password@cacheaddress.com.br:80 install packagename
```

it tells me "event not found".